# How to set environment variable to multiple MS SQL server instances running on same host?

Tags: sql-server, environment-variables, instance

I have two instances of sql server running on two different ports on the same machine.
I need to set same environment variable for these two instances to get the instance's port number.
For eg.
ENV_MSSQL_PORT = 1438 // environment variable for Instance 1 port
ENV_MSSQL_PORT = 1439 // environment variable for Instance 2 port

I want my java application to dynamically get these different ports from process/instance's environment.
Any idea?

Comment: I normally avoid it, but since you actually have two instances running on the same host machine... What's wrong with using SQL Browser Service to resolve the instance names at runtime? i.e.: configure one process to connect to `LOCALHOST\YourFirstInstanceName` and the other to `LOCALHOST\YourSecondInstanceName`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

My requirement is just to put one environment variable in the sql server process for example "MY_SQL_SERVER_PORT=1434"

 

In linux processes we can find the process environment variables under "/proc/1475/environ" .Similar way windows should have something right? I want to set a custom environment variable there.Is that possible in sql server process which is running on windows machine?

Comment: You didn't say you were using Linux. Yes SQL Browser is not available so you will need environment variables. But named instances are not supported on Linux, so not sure what your setup actually is. Can you be clearer about how SQL Server is setup, which machine is it running on?

Comment: Well if you're on Linux then just set the environment variable on the command line when launching your application, i.e.: `ENV_MSSQL_PORT=1438 java -jar /Path/To/Your/Jarfile`, and each Java application will have its own runtime instance of the `ENV_MSSQL_PORT` environment variable.